# Can’t get rid of “Finish setting up family sharing” badge

Tags: macos, icloud, notifications, bug

Even after I complete all the steps, the notification just comes back:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is this a bug or can I solve this without asking Apple for support?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Try [force quitting](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201330) Settings.

If that doesn't work, [restart your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559).

If that doesn't work either, there's probably nothing you can do about it except waiting for Apple to fix it in a new version of iOS (because you probably don't want to try setting up your device from scratch again, which also might now fix it).

Comment: it seems like i have to either wait for Apple for an update or remove myself from family share, but thanks